# Alternative to \textcolor{}{}

Tags: color

For my recent document, I have many words that I want to have a different color.

For that, I use the expression `\textcolor{color}{word}`.
It takes me a lot of time.

I'm wondering if there is a quicker alternative.

Comment: Why do you need it colored? Is the word important? `\newcommand{\important}[1]{\textcolor{importantColor}{#1}}\colorlet{importantColor}{red}` And in the document: `\important{Renato}`.

Comment: YES!!! how can I check as favorite this comment?

Comment: The core of the question is about semantics, not color per se. As such it is a duplicate. You (or someone else) could later decide that it would make much more sense to use small caps instead of color. Easy change now. Does anybody have a good duplicate at hand?

Comment: it's a presentation... I think color are more impressive in a presentation (I think)

Comment: It doesn't matter at all what it is. That is the point of semantic markup.

Comment: @RenatoP Are you using `beamer` for your presentation?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Yes, `textcolor` has problem with beamer for me! do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @C.F.G `\textcolor` works fine in beamer. If you face a problem, please ask a question including a minimal reproducible example.